# keycloak api user creation

Tags: python, keycloak

I am trying to create a user on keycloak with the API. I am coding in Python.

I have succesfully obtained the token and used it to obtain data from the API, asking for the user list:

```
endpoint = 'http://server/auth/admin/realms/master/users'
bearertok = "bearer " + token
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': bearertok }
resp = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
```

When I try to use POST to create a new user I do it like this:

```
endpoint = 'http://server/auth/admin/realms/master/users'
bearertok = "bearer " + token
data = {'username': 'xyz', 'firstName':'xyz','lastName':'xyz', 'email':'demo2@gmail.com', 'enabled':'true'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': bearertok }
resp = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=data)
```

When I run this I get a 500 error from the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"error 500" mean that the server tried to process your request but failed at it. It's not an authentication problem, it's most likely the data that you fed to your request that has incorrect syntax/content.

Try to use `json.dumps(data)` from `json` python library before passing it into your request in order to "stringify" properly the data !

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use "[python-keycloak](https://bitbucket.org/agriness/python-keycloak)" library.